# HttpClient SendAsync Cannot access a disposed object ResponseHeadersRead

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I am looking into an issue with some legacy code which is relaying a Http Request to another URL.  It is an API Controller that reads the request and forwards it to another address asynchronously.

Very rarely, it throws a "Cannot access a disposed object" exception - full stack trace shown later in this question.  It seems to be on the line where the HttpClient is calling the SendAsync method.  I think it might be the ResponseHeadersRead option - I suspect it is happening when a large packet is being sent and it gets closed because it has just read the header and quit.  Just thought I'd sanity check this with you all, for your thoughts.  I'll change the option to be ResponseContentsRead option and see how that goes (but it can take a long time for the error to surface).

Here is the code:

```
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var request = BuildRelayHttpRequest(Request);
            await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
        }


        private static HttpRequestMessage BuildRelayHttpRequest(HttpRequestMessage incomingRequest)
        {
            var forwardToUrl = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ForwardFeedURL"]);
            var relayRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(incomingRequest.Method, forwardToUrl);
            if (incomingRequest.Method != HttpMethod.Get && incomingRequest.Content != null)
            {
                relayRequest.Content = incomingRequest.Content;
            }

            //Copies contents
            relayRequest.Content = incomingRequest.Content;
            return relayRequest;
        }
```

And here is the exception:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler+LazyStreamContent'.
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.CheckDisposed()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.CopyToAsync(Stream stream, TransportContext context)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at CHO.Web.Services.ETrains.Controllers.ETrainsApiController.<CopyandForwardFeedAsyn>d__18.MoveNext() in \Controllers\MyAPIController.cs:line 289
```

Note, line 289 is the "await client.SendAsync" line of code

Answer (score 1):

Odds are there is an error code being set by the server.

Follow your code with a `response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();` that is wrapped in a Try Catch block:

```
try
{
    var request = BuildRelayHttpRequest(Request);
    await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    // Handle success
}
catch (HttpRequestException)
{
    // Handle failure
}
```

Comment: Thanks - will use this now to try and glean further information as to why it might not be forwarding.  Will see how it goes and update findings.